# Letter codes in molecular term symbols

Tags: quantum-chemistry, notation

I'm trying to find an explanation for the letter codes (X, A, B, C, etc) when you get a term symbol like this

$$X\,{}^3{\Sigma}^-_g$$

Can anyone point me to some literature that explains these letter codes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_term_symbol#Alternative_empirical_notation In this case it is referring to the ground state (I guess probably $\ce{O2}$).

Comment: have a look also in the tables at the end of any of the Herzberg books 'Molecular Spectra & Molecular Structure'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting from Hollas, *Modern Spectroscopy*, 4th ed. (p 236):

> There is a convention, which is commonly but not always used, for labelling electronic states. The ground state is labelled $X$ and higher states of the same multiplicity are labelled $A, B, C\ldots$ in order of increasing energy. States with multiplicity different from that of the ground state are labelled $a, b, c \ldots$ in order of increasing energy.

As such, for the oxygen molecule, where the lowest three states are ${}^3{\Sigma}_g^-$, ${}^1{\Delta}$ and ${}^1{\Sigma}^+_g$ (in increasing order of energy), the triplet ground state would be labelled $X$ and the next two states $a$ and $b$ respectively.

A word of caution: it seems that this convention is not always obeyed. On the next page, Hollas writes (for $\ce{I2}$, where the ground state is a singlet)

> The transition $B\,{}^3{\Sigma}_{0_u^+} - X\,{}^1{\Sigma}_g^+$ involves the $\Omega = 0$ component of the $B$ state [...] The labelling of the $B\,{}^3{\Sigma}_{0_u^+}$ state follows general usage rather than convention, which would label it $b\,{}^3{\Sigma}_{0_u^+}$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_term_symbol#Alternative_empirical_notation) also adds, although without a citation:

> In polyatomic molecules (but not in diatomics) it is customary to add a tilde (e.g. $\tilde{X}$, $\tilde{a}$) to these empirical labels to prevent possible confusion with symmetry labels based on group representations.

Comment: I don't think you explained what ${}^3{\Sigma}^{-}_g$ means.

Comment: That explanation is [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58229/what-do-these-labels-for-molecular-electronic-states-mean/).

Comment: The $\ce{^3\Sigma ^-_g}$ is a term symbol for the not-fully filled orbitals of a homo-nuclear diatomic molecule and comes from the $\ce{D_{\infty h}}$ point group. The 3 indicates a triplet spin state, $\ce{\Sigma}$ zero orbital angular momentum, *g* (gerade) means orbitals have a centre of inversion, otherwise *u* (ungerade). The superscript - indicates -1 to reflection in plane containing nuclei, i.e. no plane of reflection. A superscript + would indicate a +1 reflection, i.e. has plane. The $\ce{O2}$ ground state is $\ce{^3\Sigma ^-_g}$ .

Comment: Thanks for mentioning your source. I totally missed the footnote on that page. It's been a while since I last had to use a lot of quantum mechanics thanks for the quick refresher.

Comment: The question didn't ask for an explanation of the term symbol anyway, but I appreciate the links/explanations in the comments. :) Just want to point out that the superscript minus indicates that the wavefunction is *antisymmetric* with respect to reflection in a plane containing the nuclei, not that such a plane does not exist.

Comment: @orthocresol;  antisymmetric, yes quite correct; blame my casual language.