# Multiplicity letter codes for large amount of states

Tags: quantum-chemistry, notation, symmetry

Well, let's say we have a large amount of states computed (e.g. over 50), all with the same multiplicity.

So, our ground state can be $X^2\Sigma^+_g$ and we can continue with $B^2, C^2$ etc. as described in [Molecular orbitals symmetry - states notation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/104472/molecular-orbitals-symmetry-states-notation) and [Letter codes in molecular term symbols](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/59211/letter-codes-in-molecular-term-symbols).

But what is the convention of the number of states is larger, than the number of letters? Does any convention like $B^2_2$ exist?

Comment: My guess is that this system of letter codes loses its convenience if you are interested in more than ~10 states. It would likely be more intuitive to switch to a numerical system like $S_0$ for ground, $S_1$ for first excited singlet, etc. One issue I have hear of with this letter code is that the labels often go unchanged if a state is latter discovered to be in the wrong order. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.700.1780&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @Tyberius Thank you for the answer! The new notation seems quite nice, but, unfortunately, it omits the information about symmetry which I consider to be really important. Have you ever seen some sort of "joined usage" like $D_0\Sigma^+_g, D_1\Sigma^+_u...$?

Comment: I haven't seen it before, but I think it would be understood correctly.